# Storing lists with different values inside a for loop R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a list

```
list1 <- list()
```

and two sequences

```
seq1 <- seq(10, 1000, by  = 10)
seq2 <- seq(2, 10, by = 10)
```

I want to loop around both sequence e.g.

```
for(i in seq1){
  for(j in seq2){
    ########
    # code #
    ########
   }
}
```

such that different list are created with the different combinations of seq1 and seq2.
I need one list with multiple lists inside containing the different combinations, e.g.

list1 has multiple lists with the different seq1 and seq2 combinations((10,2), (10,4)...)

Comment: you need to specify a bit better what kind of output you're expecting.. have you tried with nested lapplys? something like: `lapply(seq1, function(x1) lapply(seq2, function(x2, x1) ##your code##))

Answer (score 2):

There are more efficient ways to achieve your goal, but if you prefer to do it via `for-loop`, then you can try

```
for(i in seq1){
  for(j in seq2){
    list1[[length(list1)+1]] <- c(i,j)
  }
}
```

such that

```
> head(list1)
[[1]]
[1] 10  2

[[2]]
[1] 20  2

[[3]]
[1] 30  2

[[4]]
[1] 40  2

[[5]]
[1] 50  2

[[6]]
[1] 60  2
```

Comment: @user9445536 I don't think your way to add variables would work in the kind of list of my solution, they are definitely different type of lists...but if you want, you should use `list1[[1]]$var1 <- list(25)` and something like that

Comment: @user9445536 the result of `expand.grid` is a dataframe and it is much easier to allocate values based on positions

Comment: @Clemsang I guess the OP just want to create nested list....not sure about the final goal

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand.grid` to have the combinations of two vectors :

```
expand.grid(seq1, seq2)
```

To have list of combinations:

```
list1 <- expand.grid(seq1, seq2)
split(list1, seq(nrow(list1)))
```

To drop names of the columns use instead:

```
split(as.matrix(list1), row(list1))
```

Comment: Thanks this helps, the list created has called the lists variables Var1 (for seq1) and Var2 (for seq2), how do I choose what I want them to be called?

Comment: @user9445536 `colnames(list1) <- c("label1", "label2")` just before split.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of calling each list, e.g. `for (i in length(list1)) { list1$i[1]  }  `

Comment: Use `for (i in 1:length(list1)) { list1[[i]][1]}`

Comment: If i want to call a function with the different lists as paramters what should I do, e.g. for each of the combinations I am calling `  function(x, y) `, with y being the different lists

Comment: Use `f(list1[[i]][1],  list1[[i]][2])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203173/discussion-between-user9445536-and-clemsang).